# Add custom block to product page on 2columns-right In Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, layout, xml

I have changed my page product layout to `2colums-right` like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-right" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Now i add my block like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-right" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="right">
            <block class="Cmsmart\Promotion\Block\Groupproduct\View" name="promotion_listproduct_view" template="Cmsmart_Promotion::promotion.phtml">       
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This block is added ok, but at the end of the page.

My issue is:

How to add this block only on the right side of the page instead of bottom of page?

Answer (score 0):

This may help for you. Your **catalog_product_view.xml** should be like this,

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!--
 /**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-right" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
        <block class="Cmsmart\Promotion\Block\Groupproduct\View" name="promotion_listproduct_view"template="Custom_module::promotion.phtml">       
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: this code will add a block at the end of the page, not on the right side where i want. but anyway,thank you.

Comment: Its working fine for me. My requirement was as same as like you mentioned. Kindly check the screenshot http://i.prntscr.com/55-gW_raRFO1BmXls7rlhQ.png